# trying to define a layout dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-layout

like lets say i have several layouts and i want to sort of randomly choose between them..

so instead of using a static layout name like :

```
setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
```

or

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_layout, container, false);
```

i will do something like:

```
public String layoutName = 'main_layout';
setContentView(R.layout[layoutName]);
// OR
return inflater.inflate(R.layout[layoutName], container, false);
```

The above doesn't work (in JS it does work)

Is there a way to do it with java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(layoutName,"layout", 
    getActivity().getPackageName());    
    setContentView(resID);
```

Or

```
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(layoutName,"layout", 
    getActivity().getPackageName());         
    View v = inflater.inflate(resID,container, false);
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. seems like i  had another issue, and i cannot define a constructor for a fragment class and therefore the above isnt much beneficial to me. Thanks though

Comment: What do you mean with: "cannot define a constructor for a fragment class"?

Comment: well i am trying to turn this:http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html#Create android so it will take the name of the layout instead of predefining it